# CSS media queries do not work for child elements

Tags: html, css

I cannot address child elements via CSS mediaqueries. How can I style the list elements in the example below for a screen width that is bigger than 800px?

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wQu9j/)

HTML

```
  <ul class="navigation">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
```

CSS

```
   .navigation > li{ display: block; width: 10em; };

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {

.navigation > li{ width: 20em; };
}
```

Comment: Do you have other code snippets ? That should work...

Comment: Note that the width specified in the media query is the width of the viewport (content) and not the width of the window (overall browser width).

Comment: sorry I had a mistake in the CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get rid of semicolons after braces. Chrome doesn't like them:

```
.navigation > li{ 
    display: block; 
    width: 10em; 
    background: red; 
    margin: 10px; 
}

@media screen and (min-width: 300px) {

    .navigation > li{ 
        width: 20em; 
    }

}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wQu9j/2/

Answer (score 1):

hope it will help you, add media queries after the regular css code,

```
  @media only screen and (mix-width: 800px) {
           //add your css it may help you

 }
```